# Div not showing on ng-click of element returned by custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a directive in which a table html is returned successfully. One of the columns is anchor link `<td><a ng-click="showLogDiv()">Show Modified Data</a></td>` on whose click i want to show a div containing further data belonging to that row but it doesnot show.

//logdetails.html - the templateUrl proprerty of my directive

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead class="table-thead">
            <tr style="background-color:#56a7d6">

                <th>AccessLogId</th>
                <th>EntityName</th>
                <th>EntityId</th>
                <th>RequestType</th>
                <th>Modified Data</th>
                <th>Creation Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="value in viewData.logdata">
                <td>{{value.AccessLogId}}</td>
                <td>{{value.EntityName}}</td>
                <td>{{value.EntityId}}</td>
                <td>{{value.RequestType}}</td>
                <!--<td><a ng-click="showLogDetails({{value.ModifiedData| json}})">Show Modified Data</a></td>-->
                <td><a ng-click="showLogDiv()">Show Modified Data</a></td>
                <td>{{value.CreatedDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--<div ng-show="divShow">Hello</div>   I want to show  {{value.ModifiedData| json}} contents here but even hardcoded Hello value not shown -->
    <div ng-show="divShow">Hello</div>
</div>
```

In controller i have

```
 $scope.divShow = false;
        $scope.showLogDiv = function () {
            alert($scope.divShow);
            $scope.divShow = true;
            alert($scope.divShow);
        };
```

My directive

```
.directive("myActivityLogs", function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            //template: '<div></div>',
            //template: '<b>{{viewData.logdata[1].ModifiedData}}</b>'
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/appScreen/logdetails.html'
            //scope: {

            //    logsData:'='
            //},
            //link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //link: function () {

            //    alert(viewData.logdata);
            //}
        };
    });
```

How to hide/show part of html returned by directive and also how can i bind data to that part?
I am new to angularjs and nothing makes sense right now so maybe i am doing things wrong way so please explain in detail it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a directive controller. You can change your directive like this:

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      templateUrl: './logdetails.html',
      scope: {
        viewData: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {

        $scope.divShow = false;

        this.showLogDiv = function() {
          $scope.divShow = true;
        };

      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
  })
```

And then change your template HTML as the following so that it uses the controller:

```
<div>
  <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead class="table-thead">
      <tr style="background-color:#56a7d6">
        <th>AccessLogId</th>
        <th>EntityName</th>
        <th>EntityId</th>
        <th>RequestType</th>
        <th>Modified Data</th>
        <th>Creation Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="value in viewData.logdata">
        <td>{{value.AccessLogId}}</td>
        <td>{{value.EntityName}}</td>
        <td>{{value.EntityId}}</td>
        <td>{{value.RequestType}}</td>
        <td><a href ng-click="ctrl.showLogDiv()">Show Modified Data</a></td>
        <td>{{value.CreatedDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div ng-show="divShow">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Notice that I've used `<a href ng-click="ctrl.showLogDiv()">`. You can refer to [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/01mme8Snkm3FH3VEzItK) to know more.